# AngularJS wait view after JSON get

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, angularjs

Firstly sorry for bad english. I have a problem about angularjs. With this http post request , i get same data from mysql json format.

```
app.controller('DeviceActivityCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http, Data,$stateParams,DeviceActivityResult) {

    //$scope.foodDistribution=null;

    if (DeviceActivityResult.status == "success") {
        $scope.deviceActivityLog = DeviceActivityResult;
        $scope.authError = 'Correct';
        alert(DeviceActivityResult.data[0].steps);
    }
    else {
        $scope.authError = 'notsuccess';
    }


});
```

The problem is here. When the view(html) is loaded, if http request didnt finish. Fail to load html. Because percent: data(is not ready). How i can wait load view(html) for json get finish its job. Thanks for help

```
<div class="inline">
                <div ui-jq="easyPieChart" ui-options="{
                  percent: ({{deviceActivityLog.data[0].activity_time}}/340)*100,
                  lineWidth: 10,
                  trackColor: '{{app.color.light}}',
                  barColor: '{{app.color.success}}',
                  scaleColor: '{{app.color.light}}',
                  size: 188,
                  lineCap: 'butt'
                }">
                    <div>
                        <span class="h2 m-l-sm step">{{(deviceActivityLog.data[0].activity_time/340)*100|number:0}}</span>%
                        <div class="text text-sm"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

----------------state---------------

```
.state('report.food', {
                url: '/{userid:[0-9]{1,4}}',
                templateUrl: 'tpl/report_food.html',
                controller: 'DeviceActivityCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    deps: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                        function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load('ui.grid').then(
                                function () {
                                    return $ocLazyLoad.load('js/app/report/reportFood.js','UiGridDemoCtrl.resolve');
                                }
                            );
                        },
                    ],
                    DeviceActivityResult: function(Data, $stateParams) {
                        return Data.post('deviceActivity',
                            {userid: $stateParams.userid}
                        );
                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using ui-router, so you can 'resolve' the state data before making the transition into it. Here is an example of how you might do that:

```
.state('yourState', {
    ...
    controller: 'DeviceActivityCtrl',
    resolve: {
        DeviceActivityResult: function(Data, $stateParams) {
            return Data.post('deviceActivity',
                {userid:$stateParams.userid}
            );
        }
    }
})


.controller('DeviceActivityCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http, DeviceActivityResult) {
    //   Data.toast(DeviceActivityResult);
    if (DeviceActivityResult.status == "success") {
        $scope.deviceActivityLog = DeviceActivityResult;
        $scope.authError = 'Correct';
    }
    else {
        $scope.authError = 'notsuccess';
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I add my state form. In this js i have 4 controller. @gpicazo

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: DeviceActivityResultProvider <- DeviceActivityResult <- DeviceActivityCtrl .I try your answer, give this error. Have you got any solution? @gpicazo

Comment: You should be able to inject the resolve object into the controller. Check that you spelled it correctly.

Comment: i update code . please help. alert in controller is work correctly. but with this error crash. @gpicazo

Comment: Not sure I understand what the problem is. If the alert is working correctly, then you are resolving the data that you  need before the controller instance is created. What error are you seeing?

Comment: you see alert in controler, it is work. but view is not working because give me this error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: DeviceActivityResultProvider <- DeviceActivityResult <- DeviceActivityCtrl .I try your answer, give this error. Have you got any solution?  @gpicazo

Comment: From what you have provided, I don't have enough information to help figure out what is wrong. However, if the controller is working correctly, then it sounds like the issue might be that you are trying to inject DeviceActivityResult into another controller that doesn't define that resolve. Are you trying to inject DeviceActivityResult into more than one controller?

Comment: Not sure then. If you can, create a plunker that reproduces the issue.